# If else statement

Tags: php, if-statement

Trying to add a 4th else statement but it is not working. Can't find an example online that works. First 3 statements work, but not the 4th. Should it be If, elseif, elseif, else or If, elseif, else, else?

```
if(empty($fromName) or empty($fromEmail) or empty($subject) or empty($comments)) {
    echo 'You cannot submit the form with empty fields. Please correct the form and resubmit.';
    return false;
}
elseif($fieldDelete == "Delete this text!"){    
    $msg ="Delete the contents of the fourth field before submitting.";
    print $msg;
}
else {
    $flgchk = mail ("$to", "$subject", "$message", "$headers"); 
    $imgfile = "images/NatMap logo2.gif"; 
    $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
    $imgbinary = fread(fopen($imgfile, "r"), filesize($imgfile));   
    echo '<img src="data:image/gif;base64,' . base64_encode($imgbinary) . '" width=427 height=72 />';
    echo "\n<br />\n<br />Thank You!  An e-mail has been sent to the National Map web team and they will get back to you in the next 24-48 hours.";
}

else ($fieldDelete == "Delete this text!"){ 
    $msg ="Delete the contents of the fourth field before submitting.";
    print $msg;
     }
```

Comment: Clearly you can't add a fourth `if` unless you turn the third one into an `elseif`. Read the code you've already written.

Comment: You can only have one `else` statement for each `if`. It's used if none of the `if` or `elseif` tests match. What does it mean to have another one?

Comment: You can't have a condition after `else`. It has to be `elseif`. And it needs to be before `else`.

Comment: `if (condition) { ... } else if (other_condition_1) { ... } else if (other_condition_2) { ... } else { ... }`

Comment: Everyone claiming to be able to program, to think logically, will see that two `else` statements following each other cannot make any possible sense! How should those two cases be separated in the flow? When and why one picked over the other?

Comment: Checkout the documentation of PHP for [**elseif**](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php)

Comment: What are you trying to do here `else ($fieldDelete == "Delete this text!"){ ` when above you have `elseif($fieldDelete == "Delete this text!"){`

Answer (score 1):

There is no `if` for your last `else` statement. It should look similar to this:

```
if (condition1) {
    /* ... */
}
elseif (condition2) {
    /* ... */
}
elseif (condition3) {
    /* ... */
}
else {
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$fromName == You can't join an `else` to as an `else`. Change it to an `else if`. For example:

```
if(empty($fromName) or empty($fromEmail) or empty($subject) or empty($comments)) {
    echo 'You cannot submit the form with empty fields. Please correct the form and resubmit.';
    return false;

}elseif($fieldDelete == "Delete this text!"){    
    $msg ="Delete the contents of the fourth field before submitting.";
    print $msg;

}elseif($fromName == "Curtisvien" || $fromName ==  "RichardMark" || $fromName == "Thomastymn"){ 

    $msg ="You are blocked."; print $msg;   

}else{
    $flgchk = mail ("$to", "$subject", "$message", "$headers"); 
    $imgfile = "images/NatMap logo2.gif"; 
    $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
    $imgbinary = fread(fopen($imgfile, "r"), filesize($imgfile));   
    echo '<img src="data:image/gif;base64,' . base64_encode($imgbinary) . '" width=427 height=72 />';
    echo "\n<br />\n<br />Thank You!  An e-mail has been sent to the National Map web team and they will get back to you in the next 24-48 hours.";
}
```

Comment: @pamfromoz If this answer fixed your problem could you accept it to close the question.

Comment: Wait, still hiccuping. This is what I have right now:

Comment: @pamfromoz I updated the answer. Is that what your looking for?

Comment: Third condition still giving me fits:                                                                                         elseif($fromName == "Curtisvien" || "RichardMark" || "Thomastymn"){
        $msg ="You are blocked.";
  print $msg; 
}

Comment: @pamfromoz I updated the answer. Is that what your looking for?

Comment: Thanks! I can get ($fromName == "Curtisvien") to work but not multiple conditions.

Comment: @pamfromoz I fixed it. You need to add `$fromName == ` for each condition

Comment: Got it!                                                                                                                   elseif  (($fromName == "Curtisvien") || ($fromName == "Thomastymn") || ($fromName == "RichardMark")) {
        $msg ="You are blocked.";
  print $msg; 
}

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use else twice. Change second last else to elseif as below:

```
if(empty($fromName) or empty($fromEmail) or empty($subject) or empty($comments)) {
    echo 'You cannot submit the form with empty fields. Please correct the form and resubmit.';
    return false;
}
elseif($fieldDelete == "Delete this text!"){    
    $msg ="Delete the contents of the fourth field before submitting.";
    print $msg;
}
elseif {
    $flgchk = mail ("$to", "$subject", "$message", "$headers"); 
    $imgfile = "images/NatMap logo2.gif"; 
    $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
    $imgbinary = fread(fopen($imgfile, "r"), filesize($imgfile));   
    echo '<img src="data:image/gif;base64,' . base64_encode($imgbinary) . '" width=427 height=72 />';
    echo "\n<br />\n<br />Thank You!  An e-mail has been sent to the National Map web team and they will get back to you in the next 24-48 hours.";
}

else ($fieldDelete == "Delete this text!"){ 
    $msg ="Delete the contents of the fourth field before submitting.";
    print $msg;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the proper way to write if....elseif...else statement. 
You should write it following :

```
if()
{
  //statement;
}elseif()
{
  //statement;
}elseif()
{
   if()
   {
     //Nested Statement;
   }else{
     //Nested Statement;
   }
}else{
  //If all of above is false then this will execute ;
}
```

There you can use any number of elseif condition using same process .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are trying to do this:

```
if (condition1) {
    do_this;
} else {
    if (condition2) {
        do_that;
    } else {
        do_something_else;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(empty($fromName) or empty($fromEmail) or empty($subject) or empty($comments)) {
    echo 'You cannot submit the form with empty fields. Please correct the form and resubmit.';
    return false;
}
elseif($fieldDelete == "Delete this text!"){    
         $msg ="Delete the contents of the fourth field before submitting.";
         print $msg;
    }
elseif  (($fromName == "Curtisvien") || ($fromName == "Thomastymn") || ($fromName == "RichardMark")) {
        $msg ="You are blocked.";
        print $msg; 
}

    else {
            $flgchk = mail ("$to", "$subject", "$message", "$headers");
            $imgfile = "images/NatMap logo2.gif";
            $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
            $imgbinary = fread(fopen($imgfile, "r"), filesize($imgfile));   
            echo '<img src="data:image/gif;base64,' . base64_encode($imgbinary) . '" width=427 height=72 />';
            echo "\n<br />\n<br />Thank You!  An e-mail has been sent to the National Map web team and they will get back to you in the next 24-48 hours.";
    }
```